GStreamer splitmuxsrc and webrtcbin pipeline not getting EOS
I'm trying to stream video files to the web browser using GStreamer (1.24.2), GStreamer-Sharp, and with the splitmuxsrc and webrtcbin elements as shown in the below pipeline:
splitmuxsrc name=concat location="D:/VideoRecording/Downloads\\Viewer\\82cf88be-754b-44c2-a5eb-bb3f97d0bc65/**" concat.video_0 !
    parsebin !
    video/x-h264 !
    rtph264pay !
    webrtcbin name=webrtcbin

This works fine except that I am trying to listen for EOS on the bus so that I can dispose the pipeline. I'm not getting an EOS.
There's not really much in the log. I'm running level 5. This is the only real thing of interest:
0:01:47.617843300 17880 000002A7840E5080 DEBUG     splitmuxpartreader gstsplitmuxpartreader.c:455:splitmux_part_pad_event:<'':audio_0> State 4 EOS event. MaxTS seen 0:01:59.992825396
0:01:47.617977000 17880 000002A7840E5080 DEBUG     splitmuxpartreader gstsplitmuxpartreader.c:455:splitmux_part_pad_event:<'':video_0> State 4 EOS event. MaxTS seen 0:01:59.991333333

I'm guessing that's not getting propagated to the pipeline for some reason, just don't know why.

After doing some more research specifically on webrtcbin, it appears that element is restricting the EOS from getting published on the bus. At least that's what was mentioned in the GStreamer issue tracker. My workaround is to add probes to the splitmuxsrc and listen for EOS there.
